# How do you rename a security group in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

The department I'm in recently changed it's name. However, in Sitecore, I have some groups whose name contains the old department name. I'm having trouble finding any way to rename these groups to use the new department name. There is no edit or rename option in the Role Manager.

Is there any way to rename a group after it has been created? Or is the only option to recreate that group, and **All its permissions** (quite the task)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore stores permissions for items in clear text and they are not linked to the role with anything but the name so if you rename a role that you have used it on items then when you rename it authors will no longer have any right. 
If you haven't used the role then you can go and change it in the aspnet_Roles table as @Bryan advises.

There is one more way. You can create a new role and give it the name you want and add the original role to it. This way authors will get the same permissions but have the new role.

Answer (score 0):

The question and the answer in the post above deals with Sitecore 6 I believe.

For people who might stumble on this post:
We have successfully renamed Roles in Sitecore 7.2 by updating database without any issues.

Following are the tables need updated with new RoleName:

**- aspnet_roles**: update the new RoleName

**- RolesInRoles**: update MemberRoleName and TargetRoleName

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the out-of-the-box Role provider, that's just standard ASP.NET Roles.  There is some discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281891/how-do-you-rename-a-role-using-membership-in-net).

If you want to get adventurous, you could just edit the role name in your Core DB, table name is aspnet_Roles.  Not sure what repercussions this wold have though.  But hey, I like adventure.  Let us know how it works.  :)

Comment: Bad idea! Because Sitecore stores the permissions in the items (as Marto explains) and the role names will not be renamed there. So if you start hacking in the database, you will end up with basically a new role that has no item permissions linked to it.